# binding data with 3d cylinder chart using asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-3.5, mschart

My data:

> **Product_C**======   **Product_B**====== **product_A**====== **Month** 
>  124=========== 101=============== 60 =============   Feb 
>   123============99=============== 59==============March
>  130===========
>   100============= 70==============April

*is it clear*  ;-) *?**

the aspx code:

```
<asp:CHART id="Chart1" runat="server">
<series>
    <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="product_A" >
</asp:Series>
<asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="product_B">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="product_C">
    </asp:Series>
    </series>
<chartareas>
  <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" > </asp:ChartArea> </chartareas>
</asp:CHART>
```

the binding code:

```
        private void BindMyChart(int firstMonth,int lastMonth )
        {
      dsDataset myDataset = new dsDataset();
      bsHelper myObj =   new   bsHelper();
      myDataset = myObj.GetCompareSalesByMonths(firstMonth,lastMonth);
      if(myDataset.myTable.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            Chart1.DataSource = myDataset.myTable;// 
            DataView dv = myDataset.myTable.DefaultView;
            Chart1.Series["product_A"].Points.DataBindXY(dv,"Product_A",dv, "month");
            Chart1.Series["product_B"].Points.DataBindXY(dv, "Product_B",dv, "month");
            Chart1.Series["product_C"].Points.DataBindXY(dv, "Product_C",dv, "month" );
            Chart1.DataBind();
         }
      }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
         BindMyChart(Convert.ToInt32(ddlfirstMonth.SelectedValue),
               Convert.ToInt32(ddllastMonth.SelectedValue));//drop down lists
            }
}
```

the web.config:

```
    <assemblies><add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, 
     Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies>
   <httpHandlers>
    <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD"      type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,      System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"   validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <handlers>
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd"   type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization,   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>  </handlers>
```

It suppose to be like the image below:
[image: chart_required] 
but, I'm getting an empty,blank chart!
the method `myDataset = myObj.GetCompareSalesByMonths(firstMonth,lastMonth);` returns the desired data.

Comment: Where does the binding code your wrote is located ? Can you paste more code, especially `Page_Load` ?

Comment: well does it actually have any records to bind, on load i suspect if anything would have been selected in those dropdowns, Can you confirm?

Comment: @V4Vendetta : All dropdowns filled correctly.. and the dataset also got a data, when I try to bind a simple chart it work, but the problem with the 3d chart..

Comment: @Salahaldin Can you show web.config have you added handler `ChartImageHandler` ?

Comment: Both handler <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/> <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>

Comment: All settings are OK,my other charts working fine, but I think the problem with the '3d chart' databinding.